# Checkingµ/Unchecking radio using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get the selected radio and to set it using angular this way:

html

```
<span class="form-group" ng-controller="FiltreFicheController as ffCtrl">
    <input type="radio" name="sur" ng-model="sur" value="1" ng-change="ffCtrl.selectRadio(1)" checked="ffCtrl.isSelected(1)">
<input type="radio" name="sur" ng-model="sur" value="4" ng-change="ffCtrl.selectRadio(4)" checked="ffCtrl.isSelected(4)">
<input type="radio" name="sur" ng-model="sur" value="6" ng-change="ffCtrl.selectRadio(6)" checked="ffCtrl.isSelected(6)">
<input type="radio" name="sur" ng-model="sur" value="8" ng-change="ffCtrl.selectRadio(8)" checked="ffCtrl.isSelected(8)">
<input type="radio" name="sur" ng-model="sur" value="12" ng-change="ffCtrl.selectRadio(12)" checked="ffCtrl.isSelected(12)">
</span>
```

js

```
app.controller('FiltreFicheController', function($scope, $location){
    this.radio = 1;

    this.selectRadio = function(numRadio){
        this.radio = numRadio;
        alert('1');
    }

    this.isSelected = function(numRadio){
        return this.radio === numRadio;
    }
});
```

Proceeding this way, i'm not getting the first radio checked. What's wrong please? I'm not getting any error using chrome's debugger.

How to make this work, please?

Comment: Just a tip, if you could use `angular.js` instead of `angular.min.js`, you will get more meaningful errors.

Comment: @runTarm, okay thank you very much, I've just updated my post.

Comment: Then you got the answer, `ng-change` have to be used with `ng-model` which is missing in your html.

Comment: @runTarm, okay, but, this still not working.

Comment: @runTarm, i've again updated my post.

Comment: What do you want to "set" after you checked the radio button?

Comment: please see here http://jsbin.com/kemid/1/ is that what you wanted ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you understand the [ng-model principle](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel) from AngularJS?

I've created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/5040/). When you click a value and set the ng-model, you already have the selected value! You can even set a different radio-button through ng-model.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <input type="radio" name="sur_0" ng-model="selected" value="1"> Value 1
  <input type="radio" name="sur_1" ng-model="selected" value="4"> Value 4
  <input type="radio" name="sur_2" ng-model="selected" value="6"> Value 6
  <input type="radio" name="sur_3" ng-model="selected" value="8"> Value 8
  <input type="radio" name="sur_4" ng-model="selected" value="12"> Value 12 <br>
  <span>The selected value: {{selected}}</span>
```

JS:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
     $scope.selected;   
}
```

EDIT: I'm not sure what you want, but now you can `alert()` the stuff you want:

```
if($scope.selected === '4') alert($scope.selected);
```

Comment: I'm in fact trying to set a controller which catches the clicks on radio to execute some instructions.

Comment: You have the "clicks". The ng-model is updating every time you click. Click at my JSFiddle link. When you click, $scope.selected is updated every time. No use for a $watch or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Why not like this:

```
<span class="form-group" ng-controller="FiltreFicheController">
    <input type="radio" name="sur" ng-model="sur" value="1" ng-change="selectRadio(1)" checked="isSelected(1)">
    <input type="radio" name="sur" ng-model="sur" value="4" ng-change="selectRadio(4)" checked="isSelected(4)">
    <input type="radio" name="sur" ng-model="sur" value="6" ng-change="selectRadio(6)" checked="isSelected(6)">
    <input type="radio" name="sur" ng-model="sur" value="8" ng-change="selectRadio(8)" checked="isSelected(8)">
    <input type="radio" name="sur" ng-model="sur" value="12" ng-change="selectRadio(12)" checked="isSelected(12)">
</span>
```

And then:

```
app.controller('FiltreFicheController', function($scope, $location){
    var radio = 1;

    $scope.selectRadio = function(numRadio){
        radio = numRadio;
        alert('1');
    }

    $scope.isSelected = function(numRadio){
        return radio === numRadio ? 'checked' : '';
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not working, I assume that it's caused by the `checked` attribute ?

Comment: Sorry, i'm not sure what are you trying to achieve, you are going through "selectRadio" each time a checkbox is selected, there you can code the logic that you want. Best.

Comment: Okay, but how to set a default checked value?

Answer (score 0):

http://jsbin.com/kemid/1/edit?html,js,output

```
<span class="form-group" ng-controller="FiltreFicheController as ffCtrl">
  <input type="radio" name="sur" ng-model="sur" value="1" ng-change="ffCtrl.selectRadio(1)" checked="ffCtrl.isSelected(1)">
<input type="radio" name="sur" ng-model="sur" value="4" ng-change="ffCtrl.selectRadio(4)" checked="ffCtrl.isSelected(4)">
  <input type="radio" name="sur" ng-model="sur" value="6" ng-change="ffCtrl.selectRadio(6)" checked="ffCtrl.isSelected(6)">
<input type="radio" name="sur" ng-model="sur" value="8" ng-change="ffCtrl.selectRadio(8)" checked="ffCtrl.isSelected(8)">
  <input type="radio" name="sur" ng-model="sur" value="12" ng-change="ffCtrl.selectRadio(12)" checked="ffCtrl.isSelected(12)">
</span>
```

JS

```
app.controller('FiltreFicheController', function($scope, $location){
    this.radio = 1;

    this.selectRadio = function(numRadio){
        this.radio = numRadio;
        alert(numRadio);
    };

    this.isSelected = function(numRadio){
        return this.radio === numRadio;
    };
});
```